# How can I fix this issue for embedding JS in an SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg

How can I correctly embed this JS into an SVG? I am trying to make a clock, and I would like it in CSS, but JS works.
This is my code:

```html
<svg version="1.1" width="200" height="200" display="block" tranform="translate(-50%,-50%)" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="innerShadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3" result="blur" />
    <feOffset in="blur" dx="2.5" dy="2.5" />
  </filter>
  <g>
    <circle
      id="shadow"
      style="fill:rgba(0,0,0,.1)"
      cx="97"
      cy="100"
      r="87"
      filter="url(#innerShadow)"
    ></circle>
    <circle
      id="circle"
      style="stroke:#fff;stroke-width:12px;fill:#20b7af"
      cx="100"
      cy="100"
      r="80"
    ></circle>
  </g>
  <g>
    <line
      x1="100"
      y1="100"
      x2="100"
      y2="55"
      transform="rotate(80 100 100)"
      style="stroke-width:3px;stroke:#fffbf9"
      id="hourhand"
    >
      <animatetransform
        attributeName="transform"
        attributeType="XML"
        type="rotate"
        dur="43200s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
      />
    </line>
    <line
      x1="100"
      y1="100"
      x2="100"
      y2="40"
      style="stroke-width:4px;stroke:#fdfdfd"
      id="minutehand"
    >
      <animatetransform
        attributeName="transform"
        attributeType="XML"
        type="rotate"
        dur="3600s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
      />
    </line>
    <line
      x1="100"
      y1="100"
      x2="100"
      y2="30"
      style="stroke-width:2px;stroke:#c1efed"
      id="secondhand"
    >
      <animatetransform
        attributeName="transform"
        attributeType="XML"
        type="rotate"
        dur="60s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
      />
    </line>
  </g>
  <circle
    id="center"
    style="fill:#128a86;stroke:#c1efed;stroke-width:2px"
    cx="100"
    cy="100"
    r="3"
  ></circle>
  <line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(30 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"></line>
  <line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(60 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"></line>
  <line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(90 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"></line>
  <line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(120 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"></line>
  <line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(150 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"></line>
  <line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(180 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"></line>
  <line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(210 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"></line>
  <line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(240 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"></line>
  <line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(270 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"></line>
  <line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(300 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"></line>
  <line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(330 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"></line>
  <line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(360 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"></line>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var hands = [];
    hands.push(document.querySelector('#secondhand > *'));
    hands.push(document.querySelector('#minutehand > *'));
    hands.push(document.querySelector('#hourhand > *'));
    
    function shifter(val) {
      return [val, 100, 100].join(' ');
    }
    
    var date = new Date();
    var hoursAngle = 360 * date.getHours() / 12 + date.getMinutes() / 2;
    var minuteAngle = 360 * date.getMinutes() / 60;
    var secAngle = 360 * date.getSeconds() / 60;

    hands[0].setAttribute('from', shifter(secAngle));
    hands[0].setAttribute('to', shifter(secAngle + 360));
    hands[1].setAttribute('from', shifter(minuteAngle));
    hands[1].setAttribute('to', shifter(minuteAngle + 360));
    hands[2].setAttribute('from', shifter(hoursAngle));
    hands[2].setAttribute('to', shifter(hoursAngle + 360));
  </script>
</svg>
```

If this isn't possible I understand, but I would like a solution. I am running on repl.it.
It gives this XML Document Tree when I open it

```xml
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<svg xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="200" display="block" tranform="translate(-50%,-50%)">
<filter id="innerShadow" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%">
<feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>
<feOffset in="blur" dx="2.5" dy="2.5"/>
</filter>
<g>
<circle id="shadow" style="fill:rgba(0,0,0,.1)" cx="97" cy="100" r="87" filter="url(#innerShadow)"/>
<circle id="circle" style="stroke:#fff;stroke-width:12px;fill:#20b7af" cx="100" cy="100" r="80"/>
</g>
<g>
<line x1="100" y1="100" x2="100" y2="55" transform="rotate(80 100 100)" style="stroke-width:3px;stroke:#fffbf9" id="hourhand">
<animatetransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" dur="43200s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</line>
<line x1="100" y1="100" x2="100" y2="40" style="stroke-width:4px;stroke:#fdfdfd" id="minutehand">
<animatetransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" dur="3600s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</line>
<line x1="100" y1="100" x2="100" y2="30" style="stroke-width:2px;stroke:#c1efed" id="secondhand">
<animatetransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" dur="60s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</line>
</g>
<circle id="center" style="fill:#128a86;stroke:#c1efed;stroke-width:2px" cx="100" cy="100" r="3"/>
<line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(30 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"/>
<line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(60 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"/>
<line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(90 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"/>
<line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(120 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"/>
<line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(150 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"/>
<line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(180 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"/>
<line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(210 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"/>
<line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(240 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"/>
<line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(270 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"/>
<line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(300 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"/>
<line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(330 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"/>
<line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="40" transform="rotate(360 100 100)" stroke="#ffffff"/>
<script type="text/javascript"> var hands = []; hands.push(document.querySelector('#secondhand > *')); hands.push(document.querySelector('#minutehand > *')); hands.push(document.querySelector('#hourhand > *')); function shifter(val) { return [val, 100, 100].join(' '); } var date = new Date(); var hoursAngle = 360 * date.getHours() / 12 + date.getMinutes() / 2; var minuteAngle = 360 * date.getMinutes() / 60; var secAngle = 360 * date.getSeconds() / 60; hands[0].setAttribute('from', shifter(secAngle)); hands[0].setAttribute('to', shifter(secAngle + 360)); hands[1].setAttribute('from', shifter(minuteAngle)); hands[1].setAttribute('to', shifter(minuteAngle + 360)); hands[2].setAttribute('from', shifter(hoursAngle)); hands[2].setAttribute('to', shifter(hoursAngle + 360)); </script>
</svg>
```

If I add !CDATA[[ script ]] it just gives a plain out error. Like error detected on line X.

Comment: While you can put JS in SVG, when loading the SVG _as an image_ (i.e. using the `<img>` tag) that JS will do absolutely nothing because the image is treated as static content, not active content. You'd have to inline the SVG _with_ its JS into a document for it to do anything. But if you're inlining it, the SVG element is no longer versioned, and has no namespace. And the script tag no longer has a type attribute (unless you're _not_ writing JS, then it does).

Comment: Can you provide the error message?

Comment: How exactly did you run it on repl.it?

Comment: If this is ran as standalone SVG, `animatetransform` should be `animateTransform`

Comment: The reason a browser displays `This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.` for an svg file is because you have a typo in the xmlns. It should be `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` (http, not https).

Comment: After fixing the xmlns and animateTransform in your first snippet, I can load it as standalone SVG in Edge, and the hands move.

Comment: Also note that if you try to use a `%` sign in the svg transform like `"translate(-50%,-50%)"` , it will result in an error. (You also had a typo for 'transform': it was `tranform` in the original)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG files can either link to a JavaScript file or have the JavaScript in a script element. In the later case, now that SVG is XML you need to put all the JS code in a CDATA element. There are `//` in front of `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` because these two tags are not JavaScript, but it is still valid XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter height="140%" id="innerShadow" width="140%" x="-20%" y="-20%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" result="blur" stdDeviation="3"/>
    <feOffset dx="2.5" dy="2.5" in="blur"/>
  </filter>
  <g>
    <circle cx="97" cy="100" filter="url(#innerShadow)" id="shadow" r="87" style="fill:rgba(0,0,0,.1)"/>
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" id="circle" r="80" style="stroke:#fff;stroke-width:12px;fill:#20b7af"/>
  </g>
  <g>
    <line id="hourhand" style="stroke-width:3px;stroke:#fffbf9" transform="rotate(80 100 100)" x1="100" x2="100" y1="100" y2="55">
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" dur="43200s" repeatCount="indefinite" type="rotate"/>
    </line>
    <line id="minutehand" style="stroke-width:4px;stroke:#fdfdfd" x1="100" x2="100" y1="100" y2="40">
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" dur="3600s" repeatCount="indefinite" type="rotate"/>
    </line>
    <line id="secondhand" style="stroke-width:2px;stroke:#c1efed" x1="100" x2="100" y1="100" y2="30">
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" dur="60s" repeatCount="indefinite" type="rotate"/>
    </line>
  </g>
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" id="center" r="3" style="fill:#128a86;stroke:#c1efed;stroke-width:2px"/>
  <line stroke="#ffffff" transform="rotate(30 100 100)" x1="100" x2="100" y1="20" y2="40"/>
  <line stroke="#ffffff" transform="rotate(60 100 100)" x1="100" x2="100" y1="20" y2="40"/>
  <line stroke="#ffffff" transform="rotate(90 100 100)" x1="100" x2="100" y1="20" y2="40"/>
  <line stroke="#ffffff" transform="rotate(120 100 100)" x1="100" x2="100" y1="20" y2="40"/>
  <line stroke="#ffffff" transform="rotate(150 100 100)" x1="100" x2="100" y1="20" y2="40"/>
  <line stroke="#ffffff" transform="rotate(180 100 100)" x1="100" x2="100" y1="20" y2="40"/>
  <line stroke="#ffffff" transform="rotate(210 100 100)" x1="100" x2="100" y1="20" y2="40"/>
  <line stroke="#ffffff" transform="rotate(240 100 100)" x1="100" x2="100" y1="20" y2="40"/>
  <line stroke="#ffffff" transform="rotate(270 100 100)" x1="100" x2="100" y1="20" y2="40"/>
  <line stroke="#ffffff" transform="rotate(300 100 100)" x1="100" x2="100" y1="20" y2="40"/>
  <line stroke="#ffffff" transform="rotate(330 100 100)" x1="100" x2="100" y1="20" y2="40"/>
  <line stroke="#ffffff" transform="rotate(360 100 100)" x1="100" x2="100" y1="20" y2="40"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var hands = [];
    console.log(hands);
    hands.push(document.querySelector('#secondhand >*'));
    hands.push(document.querySelector('#minutehand >*'));
    hands.push(document.querySelector('#hourhand >*'));
    
    function shifter(val) {
      return [val, 100, 100].join(' ');
    }
    
    var date = new Date();
    var hoursAngle = 360 * date.getHours() / 12 + date.getMinutes() / 2;
    var minuteAngle = 360 * date.getMinutes() / 60;
    var secAngle = 360 * date.getSeconds() / 60;

    hands[0].setAttribute('from', shifter(secAngle));
    hands[0].setAttribute('to', shifter(secAngle + 360));
    hands[1].setAttribute('from', shifter(minuteAngle));
    hands[1].setAttribute('to', shifter(minuteAngle + 360));
    hands[2].setAttribute('from', shifter(hoursAngle));
    hands[2].setAttribute('to', shifter(hoursAngle + 360));
    //]]></script>
</svg>
```

Displaying the clock can either be done as embedded code in the HTML or as a reference to the SVG file. In the later case you need to use the object or embed element in HTML. You cannot refer to the SVG file in CSS or in an img element if you need the JS code to run... Here I made an object element with a data URI (because I cannot refer to a real file here on ST) with the exact same code as above:

```html
<object width="200" height="200" data="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"></object>
```

Comment: Thanks, I, being me, typed the wrong thing and messed it up, also thanks for the `object` element example as they don't work in img tags (probably some HTML protection).